# Wrong font although it is installed

Tags: delphi, canvas, fonts, truetype

I draw text on a canvas and set the font by:

```
 Image3.Canvas.font.name := 'Arial Narrow';
```

Everything is right on my machine. But on another pc from my client the wrong font (bigger) is printed.
So I installed all `Arial Narrow` fonts on the clients machine. But I still have the wrong font.

Edit: Font seems to be right, but not scale:

**This is the problem**
Windows 7 has on its Control Panel, Appearance and Personalization, Display setting, an ability to Magnify the text and other items by 125% or 150%.

Any ideas how to get those settings?

Comment: probably the other pc uses font substitution for `Arial Narrow` - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/12b37082-c4e6-4beb-9bfb-7b992ebc2a1a/tip-how-to-substitute-any-font-with-for-any-other-font?forum=w7itproui

Comment: Is it really a different font? It is also possible your client has a different DPI setting.

Comment: DPI should not matter when i print it with the printer or to a pdf file?

Comment: I checked registry settings ../FontSubstitutes and everything is the same on the clients machine

Comment: Is Arial Narrow - internatinal TTF ? maybe it is selected codepage/charset that is missed fro mthe font ?

Comment: problem is already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the DPI and adjusting the font size did it for me:

```
DC := GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
try
  DPI:=GetDeviceCaps(DC,LOGPIXELSY);
finally
  ReleaseDC(DC,HWND_DESKTOP);
end;
Image3.Canvas.font.size := round(myConstant*96/DPI);
```

Comment: Instead of `DPI` in your code use just [`PixelsPerInch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PixelsPerInch).

Comment: Interesting. But starting with Windows 8.1 each display has its own separate DPI.

Answer (score 0):

At first you set the size of the image as bitmap,Because before using canvas, bitmap has to be created.

so that `bitmap.canvas.font` does have a default size,

so later it wont increase its size.So the  original font will be produced.

Comment: No. You don't have to create any bitmap to render on `TImage.Canvas`.

Comment: i set the size of the bitmap

Comment: @zoidbergi, well if you are drawing on `TImage.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas` then setup the font on that canvas (in your question you have shown that you use `TImage.Canvas`).